# How I can move to the next page in react JavaScript by clicking Google Sign in Page along with loading Google data?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx, create-react-app

I have been trying to move to the next page by clicking on Google sign in button. Before it, I want to load data from Google API, then it should automatically load the other page.

I have tried logging with Google using Google API I want to load the other page by clicking the Google sign in button and it should load the other page in a time span that it loads the data as well.

This is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import GoogleLogin from "react-google-login";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Registeration = (props) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");

  const responseGoogle = async (response) => {
    setName(response.profileObj.name);
    setEmail(response.profileObj.email);
    setUrl(response.profileObj.imageUrl);

    props.setDataFromGoogle(response.profileObj.givenName);
    props.setDataFromGoogle1(response.profileObj.familyName);

    console.log(response);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="backGroundRedRegisteration">
        <div className="registerationFirstPageLogo">
          <div>
            <img src={logoFamily} alt="" className="familyLogo" />
          </div>

          <div>
            <BiPlusMedical className="plusIcon" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="mainContainerRegisteration">
        <div className="registerationContentContainer">
          <div className="googleBtnDiv">
            <img src={googleIcon} alt="" className="googleIcon" />
            <Link to="/RegisterationSecondS">
              <GoogleLogin
                className="btnGoogle"
                clientId="677360402906- 
                                dm66f7qv5dkfaoqt0kleshkeoma85fjn.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                buttonText="Continue with Google"
                onSuccess={responseGoogle}
                onFailure={responseGoogle}
                cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
              />
            </Link>
          </div>

          <div>
            <a href="#">Help me login</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Registeration;
```

Comment: Issue an imperative navigation in your `responseGoogle` callback depending on response value.

Comment: thanks i already solved issue